I messed up, where do I go from here
I was recently named a project lead at work.  A couple weeks ago I helped hire a new employee for that team.  The majority of the job is basically doing second level tech support for a client's website, though there's a lot of buzz around a redesign effort that we are pursuing.  The new person has a lot of passion for design and large products, but we told her that this is primarily a troubleshooting job.  On her first day, I told her that my top priority was to get some work off another team member's plate because he has been covering the job she's filling. I wanted her to take a LinkedIn Learning training for SSRS, a tool that she's going to use.  When I checked in with her the next day, she told me that she'd started a list of all the errors of the website that we support.  Her intent was that this will somehow guide the redesign effort.  I told her that I wasn't sure how that would be helpful.  Maybe if the redesign is fixing the website, it could be useful, but if we're completely starting over, then what she's working on isn't a useful tool.
Fast forward a week.  This past Monday, the week after she started, I called to check in on her and verify that she had the software she needed, except access to the client's system (there was a hang-up there that I knew about).  She told me she did and that she was still working on this document.  I told her that I needed her to do the training I sent her (from my manager).  She told me that she's a hands on learner and so she needs the environment to learn the program.  Besides she arranged to shadow the guy who's overwhelmed with work when we were in the office the next day.  I told her again that I need her to do the training.  On Tuesday I walked past her desk a few times and didn't see the training, but saw the website up.  I didn't confront her.  On Wednesday, I went to a team meeting where my manager referenced the 17 page document that she produced and sent him.  I was pretty upset.  Based on where she was on Monday, I was pretty sure that she chose to ignore my instruction and move on with her priority.
In the meantime I was working on a plan to pitch to the client for the redesign.  I did things like create a WBS for estimation purposes, started researching whether we want to use a different backend than what we planned, plus my regular work, which includes checking statuses of tickets and talking to other team members and managers that we work with.  Because of the work that I was doing, someone in the company looped her into an email chain about a project she had worked on (she came in from being an intern with another department).  So on Thursday she came in excited, I assume because she could advise and contribute to the redesign project.  We talked a little about who she thought I could talk to and the conversation went to her document.  I tried to find a nice way to ask what I could do with it?  I showed her that giving a list of attributes that breaks the page won't help with future development because we're going to use our standards and I showed how that looks in a story on JIRA. She defended her work, but I was upset that she finished it, I didn't pay close attention.  I eventually asked her if she had done the training I asked for.  She seemed offended that I asked because that's not how she learns.  I reminded her that LinkedIn has exercise files so she doesn't need the client's environment to do the training and she told me that the environment is all she needs because she can figure out how to move around the program.  Eventually I moved us into a different room so we could talk.  And I made a bad situation worse.  I raised my voice, I told her that I feel like she's telling me to "fuck off".  I can't imagine I could have done much more wrong.  I told her that I have no confidence that she's going to do tickets when she gets the access to the back end that she needs.  She said obviously she will.  I told her that she keeps saying obviously, but I havent' seen her do the one task I've given her.  Her work ethic or what I can expect is not obvious to me.  We had to end because we had to get to a meeting.
We didn't' talk the rest of the day.  I called her today (Friday, we WFH Mon, Wed, Fri).  She didn't answer, so I left a voicemail where I told her I owed her an apology for the way I handled the conversation.  There was nothing okay about what I did.  We need to talk and address the situation and then figure out how to work together.  I told her to call me.  That was at 9:20 (she starts at 9) it's a little before 5 now and she hasn't called.
So, what I want to know is where do we go from here?  I am not proud of how I handled things on Thursday.  I wouldn't argue with her if she said I had been dismissive of her for the two weeks she's been on my team, though I would say it hasn't been intentional.  I assume I won't hear from her until I see her in the office on Tuesday.

TL;DR. We don't need all the backstory, and it distracts from your actual question.

Seconded, I'm not going to VTC, but this question needs to be pruned down to the relevant parts, less soap-opera script.

“So, what I want to know is where do we go from here” - You set a reasonable deadline for the completed training. If it’s NOT completed then take the next step you find appropriate to get rid of this employee. The responses you have received are excuses for not doing the training which is honestly probably extremely boring. You can also just ask her to complete tasks without the training with reasonable deadlines you could achieve yourself.

Can you clarify "team lead". Is this person your direct report or do you both report to the same manager?

I should probably clarify that I only suggested setting a reasonable timeline for the training to be completed because it was one of the first tasks assigned to the employee, and they ignored those directions. Whether the training is boring or even not worth completing is, at this point, irrelevant. Everyone has to do things they don't want to do, and sometimes, just completing the task is important. I would suggest that perhaps simply assigning her an actual task and finding out if she can complete it might be the better approach.

@Donald: the employee is not refusing the training, they are saying that that they are blocked from doing the training (efficiently) by not having access. This may or may not be a correct assessment. Hard to tell.

@Hilmar - The employee has done flyer training for weeks. That effectively refusing to do it.

@Hilmar the employee is definitely refusing to do the training. There's nothing in the post about not having access to it, its a LinkedIn training.

The bottom line is very very simple. This is so simple, that let's focus just on the specific points.
You have been tasked to manage a project. You hired (helped) a person that repeatedly ignored your specific instructions.
This person also went over your head.

They don't respect your authority.
They don't follow your specific instructions.
They don't listen to your corrections of their behavior.
They don't respect the management hierarchy

They are a loose cannon that make you look like you can't do your job. Because you allow them to do what they are doing, that is demonstratively so. (Sorry)
The solution is also simple.
Managers must manage. You are not asking this person if they would like to do what you ask. You are running a project.
When you task someone (management 101):

They do it
They ask for clarification
They explain why you are wrong
They quit

Ignoring you isn't on the list. Going around you isn't on the list.
This is your career growth and this person is about to blow it up. Lose the emotion. Tell them to fall in line or get out now. No other choices are acceptable. It is that simple.

@Fe2O3 Normally, I would start out an answer to this type of question by explaining the Peter Principle. I believe that when I fire someone it is a failure on my part. What didn't I do that I could have to fix the problem. I hired them, they should have excelled. So, don't take my answer with a view of "BE A HAMMER". It is not that at all. These are people with livelihoods not machines we are talking about. With what the OP described, the employee doesn't show any sign of respect after multiple interactions. That can't stand if the OP is to be a team lead or grow as a manager.

@Fe2O3 I don't mind your downvote. I have a company and been doing this for 40+ years. Teaching people how to manage while not oppressive is job unto itself. The basics do require mutual respect.

@Fe2O3  My style is to focus on the biggest issue(s) first. I like to rate using fibonacci sequence when doing project mangement. In the OP's case, I saw the lack of respect after multiple interactions as the greatest problem by far. With respect established, then the OP's management training can continue. Without it, management training is scuttled.

"They explain why you are wrong" - isn't this what OP said? The employee has said several times that training would be a useless time investment for her. I don't try to argue that this behaviour was entirely unprofessional, but... Well, if I say "I don't need to spend time on this training", I would enjoy manager listening to this opinion, people are different. If the access mentioned above is some kind of sandbox/test env, where mistakes aren't costly, the manager could grant it and see if it works. If it does, employee didn't have to trash their time, and manager didn't lose anything.

@SUTerliakov  How would an new hire know what training is required to be successful? To ignore the manager (Team Lead's) requirements for the job is just pushback. A better example of "You're wrong" would be "wire this for 240v" when it is a 120v device. That is something that can be discussed and reviewed. "I don't feel like it", which is what the intern is saying, isn't the same as explaining why the manager is wrong. Surely the intern could take the training tests to prove the knowledge? Why not, do they know better than the team lead what is required? How?

Yes, if there are training tests that can be passed without actually passing the rest of the course, that's the ideal solution.

You hired the wrong person for the job you need done.
What you wanted: someone who is going to basically act as IT serve your customers by helping them troubleshoot issues/generating reports and performing other IT tasks.
What you got: someone who is excited to be a developer and doesn't seem terribly interested in your top priority for her.

On her first day, I told her that my top priority was to get some work off another team member's plate because he has been covering the job she's filling. I wanted her to take a LinkedIn Learning training for SSRS, a tool that she's going to use. . She told me that she's a hands on learner and so she needs the environment to learn the program. <We haven't been able to give her the access to the environment because of reasons. And instead of doing the training like she was supposed to she spent the past week generating a 17 page document that lists the errors in a website that we are planning on redesigning from scratch.>...

What I got from this is that instead of doing what you told them to do. New Hire is doing what they want to do. I get it, designing something new is fun and cool. Doing a training on how to use a Microsoft (shudder) program to provide IT support is lame, boring, and basically the opposite of fun.
And yes... I know many people think that I am a "hands on learner" I learn better thru application too. But guess what, a lot of software training tutorials are "hands on", they teach how to do something, have you do that thing in a controlled environment, where you aren't likely to run into weird bugs. And repeat until they have taught you how to use all the features the tutorial was designed to cover.
For everyone who thinks that manuals/tutorials are pointless, there is a reason why RTFM is an acronym. There are a lot of software tools out there that have very bad, unintuitive designs. Microsoft bless their heart, has made more then their fair share of these. Which take a very long time to figure out unless you read the manual/follow a tutorial/have used a similar tool in the past so know what the tool is supposed to do.
